# Set all input values according to another input value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following:

```
<input type="text" value="100" name="setgroup50" />
<input type="submit" value="Set all" />
<input type="text" value="10" name="group50" />
<input type="text" value="10" name="group50" />
<input type="text" value="10" name="group50" />
```

I am trying to get all the values of "group50" inputs to equal the user input in the "setgroup50" field.

I found this but have no idea what to do with it:

```
$(".group50").val("test");
```

so to summarize I have two questions:

1. How do I execute the JavaScript when the button is clicked? (I'm assuming onclick)
2. How do I take the variable from "setgroup50" and use it in the above snippet?

Comment: why downvoting this?

Comment: I don't know why anybody is down voting it.

Comment: I personally didn't downvote your question and the people who downvote without commenting to explain why need to quit. But the reason you're getting downvoted is that you simply ask how to do something without making any effort to try it yourself. And apparently very little effort to 'Google' it if that code snippet is all you found. SO is a place to get help when you have put forth the effort and are having trouble with your code. The normal procedure here is to post the code you have tried. Preferably create a fiddle (www.jsfiddle.net) and may here will be glad to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Bind `click` event on the submit button
2. Get the value from the set-textbox by using attribute-value selector
3. Set the value to all the other inputs

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(':submit').click(function() {
    $('[name="group50"]').val($('[name="setgroup50"]').val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="100" name="setgroup50" />
<input type="submit" value="Set all" />
<input type="text" value="10" name="group50" />
<input type="text" value="10" name="group50" />
<input type="text" value="10" name="group50" />
```

Answer (score 1):

1. How do I execute the JavaScript when the button is clicked? (I'm assuming onclick)

You can either hook it to the html element

```
<input type="submit" value="Set all" onClick="function(){//CodeInHere}"/>
```

or add an event listener

```
$('input').on('click',function(){});
```

2. How do I take the variable from "setgroup50" and use it in the above snippet?

   ```
   $('input').on('click', function () {
       var setgroup50Value = $('[name="setgroup50"]').val();
       $('[name="group50"]').val(setgroup50Value);
   });
   ```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/meehanman/ufcvky1g/)

Answer (score -1):

First, you should go here http://google.com/?q=jquery+tutorial+for+beginners and learn jQuery. If you're going to be doing website front end work it will make your life and your output better.

Second check out this fiddle I created for you answering your question. Note that I have included jQuery in the left bar. Without this the jQuery code would not work. Also make note of jsfiddle.net itself. It's a great place for proof of concept work. Then if you have a problem you can post a link to the work you've done here and people can help. http://jsfiddle.net/p23eyqge/

```
// "$(function(){" is a jquery short cut for the jquery function: 
// "$(document).ready(function(){ ... code goes here ... });"
// this function executes when the DOM is fully loaded.
// trying to set Event Listners like click handlers before the DOM has fully loaded 
// usually doesn't work. 
$(function(){
    // this add the "function" as a click event handler on the input with type="submit"
    $('input:submit').click(function(){
        // this sets the value of all inputs with the name="group50" 
        // to the value of the input with the name="setgroup50"
       $('input[name="group50"]').val($('input[name="setgroup50"]').val());
    });
});
```

I hope this helps. But before asking more "how to" questions here. learn some jquery and give it your best shot in fiddle. If you have problems figuring out why your code doesn't work as expected, then ask it here and post a link to your fiddle.

Comment: Learn jQuery... and Learn CSS3... Jquery uses CSS3 selectors to select elements to act on. Elements can be accessed by class simply by "$('.className')" The '.' represents classes. Elements can be accessed by ID by "$('#id')". The '#' represents IDs. You can do the same thing with $'([class=""]') or $('[id=""]') but it's shorter the other way. You can select all elements within another element by chaining selectors. $('ul#mylist li') will select all list items inside the UL with the ID="mylist". jQuery is very powerful and very useful. Learning the CSS3 Selectors will help you use it.